# Recognize coloured text with Tesseract (Tess4J)

Tags: java, ocr, bufferedimage, tesseract

Im working with text recognition with Java and Tess4J. Im recognizing black and red images (separately), both with white background, very clear. With the black ones, it works perfectly, but with the red ones, tesseract just goes crazy. I tried adding the variable ("editor_image_text_color", "RED"), but it does not help at all.
Right now, what I do for the red ones is scan the whole image and set every red pixel to black, which I find very inefficient, because I need a few calculations for each pixel, due to the pictures have different intensity of red that I have to conserve.
Thanks a lot!

For instance:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/3eu9.png/ does always give me a 9, but
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/efxf.png/ does not, is like if it were losing the number in the preprocessing, because the black ones work extremely well, but the red ones arent any better than a random number.

Comment: It would be nice to see picture samples. Sounds a little bit strange because Tesseract does binarization before processing an image (that's as I understood is exactly what are you doing manually)

Comment: And do you maybe know why could the binarization fail? I think the pictures are very clear, even though the size is low (but I guess that's nothing very strange for OCR)

Comment: Can you adjust the threshold of the binarization process? Could help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert the colored image to grayscale using `ImageHelper.convertImageToGrayscale(BufferedImage image)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer nguyenq, I tried that function and it didn't work very well, but after checking out that ImageHelper class, I used the method:

```
ImageHelper.convertImageToBinary(BufferedImage image)
```

and it works quite well, thanks!

Comment: My intent was to have Tesseract's thresholding algorithm to create the binary image from the grayscale, but your choice made sense b/c the image was bitonal (red and white). Glad that it worked for you.